# How to override a phtml file in vendor folder

Tags: magento2, overrides, phtml

I am trying to override a file located in

```
/html/vendor/mirasvit/module-search-ultimate/src/Search/view/frontend/templates/index/magefan/blog/post.phtml
```

I have created a path under my custom theme like this but the override does not apply

```
/html/app/design/frontend/mytheme/Mirasvit_SearchUltimate_Search/templates/index/magefan/blog/post.phtml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic of overwrite template is correct, but i have 2 questions.

1. Is `/mytheme/` just simplify and you have path like `/<vendor>/<theme>/`?
2. Are you sure the module name is `Mirasvit_SearchUltimate_Search` with 2 underscores?

   You can check module name in `vendor/mirasvit/module-search-ultimate/src/Search/registration.php`.

   I just checked and see that Module name is `Mirasvit_Search`

In this case the correct path should be `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Mirasvit_Search/templates/index/magefan/blog/post.phtml`

Comment: You are right. Thanks!